# Magento 2 issues with programmatically creating child blocks

Tags: magento2, blocks, magento2.2.2

In trying to come up with my own solution to [my other active question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/205348/35344), I've been trying to add child blocks to my own custom block so that I can use them as renderers for the product options, thus replicating the general way that product forms are rendered on the product page.

The problem is that I get an error stating that the block I'm trying to add already exists. Taking that into account, I have tried several methods of determining if the child block already exists and none of them have worked yet.

**Attempt 1** (check to see if we can get the child block)

```
protected function _prepareLayout() {
    if (!$this->getChildBlock('default')) {
        $childBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType', 'product.info.options.default');
        $childBlock->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml');
        $this->addChild('default', $childBlock);
    }
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

**Attempt 2** (check to see if the name already exists in layout)

```
protected function _prepareLayout() {
    $layout = $this->getLayout()
    if (!$layout->getChildName($this->getNameInLayout(), 'default')) {
        $childBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType', 'product.info.options.default');
        $childBlock->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml');
        $this->addChild('default', $childBlock);
    }
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

**Attempt 3** (check local variable to determine if this code has already been run)

```
protected function _prepareLayout() {
    if (!$this->_layoutPrepared) {
        $childBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType', 'product.info.options.default');
        $childBlock->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml');
        $this->addChild('default', $childBlock);
        $this->_layoutPrepared = true;
    }
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

In each attempt, I have received the frontend error of "We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content." (which is spectacularly helpful considering error display is turned on).

From the exception log, I find this error twice: `report.CRITICAL: Element with ID 'form_0.default' is already defined.` which tells me that the code appears to be running multiple times.

What I gather from this is that *somehow* the code is being run three times: once successfully, and twice with errors. If I comment out the code, the child block cannot be found at all so it is not the case that there is a block with the same alias. It also doesn't matter what the alias is, as this has been tested with multiple variations.

I can't see any reason why `_prepareLayout` would get called multiple times, nor why it wouldn't be able to find the already existing child blocks and prevent the duplication using the code I have tried.

Any assistance in resolving this issue would be welcomed.

For reference, if relevant, this is Magento Commerce 2.2.2.

Comment: You need to set Magento mode to Developer mode to see the errors in the front end. Also try using Xdebug to line by line debug the issue.

Comment: Awww, I wish it had been that simple.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you make :

```
$childBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(...)
```

you create the block in the layout, then when you try to do :

```
$this->addChild('default', $childBlock);
```

you also add the block in the layout.

That's why you have an error.

Comment: What is the fix for this question?